# Problem with integrating $\int t^2\sqrt t\, dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Here is the equation:
$$\int t^2 \sqrt{t}dt$$

Here is my answer:
$$\int t^2 \sqrt{t} = \dfrac12 \int t^{1/2}2t = \dfrac12 \dfrac{t^{3/2}}{3/2} = \dfrac12 \cdot \dfrac23 t^{3/2} + c$$

whereas here is the correct answer:

$$\dfrac27 \dfrac{t^{7}}2 + c$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have $$\int t^{\left(2+\frac12\right)} dt=\int t^{\frac52}dt$$ right?

Comment: no i do not have that

Comment: then what do you have ?

Comment: I have what is above and I already notice my mistake. thank you!

Comment: @Cash Vai : are you doing integration by parts.

Comment: I'm ding some revision exercises

Comment: @CashVai I have removed the image and written out the math you had using TeX, which is used by this website to make the math formulas appear legible and nice. Read [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more details. Kindly use TeX to write down the the math instead of posting images in future.

Comment: @CashVai Thanks. Could you also fix the rest of your questions by replacing the image with math written in TeX?

Comment: @CashVai: Let $t=x^2$ then $\mathrm{d}t=2x$ $\mathrm{d}x$. Substituting we get, $$2\int x^6 \mathrm{d}x$$ which simplifies to $\dfrac{2x^7}{7}+C$. Often this techniques is helpful if direct manipulation of fractions seems difficult.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int t^2(t^{1/2}) dt=  \int t^{(2 + 1/2)} \,dt=  \int t^{\large \frac52}dt$$

Now use the power rule to integrate!

$$\int ax^{n} \,dx = \dfrac {ax^{n+1}}{n+1},\quad n\neq -1$$

Applying that here, noting that $\frac 52 + 1 = \frac 52 + \frac 22 = \frac 72$: $$\int t^{\large \frac52}dt =  \frac{t^{\large \frac 72}}{\large \frac 72} + C =  \frac 27 t^{\large \frac 72} + C $$

Comment: Looks like you spotted it +1

Answer (score 2):

$$t^2\sqrt{t}=t^\frac{5}{2}$$
$$\int t^\frac{5}{2}dt=\frac{t^{\frac{5}{2}+1}}{\frac{5}{2}+1}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int t^2\sqrt{t} \  dt = \int t^2\cdot t^{\frac{1}{2}} \  dt = \int t^{\frac{5}{2}} \  dt = \frac{t^{\frac{5}{2}+1}}{\frac{5}{2}+1}+C=\frac{t^{\frac{7}{2}}}{\frac{7}{2}}+C =\frac{2}{7}t^{\frac{7}{2}}+C$$